# How do I specify the window/browser size of the Cypress app in headless mode?

Tags: cypress

I do not mean the viewport. I mean more like the entire browser including the test runner bar on the side. I am posting screenshots from my local "cypress run" vs in aws to make it clear.

As you can see the second has an overall square shape that is squishing the viewport and I cant see much like this.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean the size of the browser ?

Comment: yes, exactly ... i edited my question to make it clearer, thanks

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Set-screen-size-when-running-headless